# For loop length problems

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, for-loop

The code is to input strings at run time but the code is accepting string one less than the mentioned sized n? Where is the error?

suppose n=3,but the loop is running only twice i.e. n-1 times thus taking only two strings as input

```
int main(){
  int n; 
  cin>>n;
  char str[n][100];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    char c; 
    int j=0; 
    while((c=getchar())!='\n') 
    {  
      str[i][j++] = c; 
    }  
    str[i][j] ='\0'; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude compiler is not showing anykind of warning or error

Comment: @SrjSunny what is the actual problem you are having? The question is a bit confusing. The code seems at a glance to be correct.

Comment: @pepperjack when i enter size of n=3 the loop runs only for 2 times thus taking only two strings.I want to know why?

Comment: @pepperjack please once try it in your compiler

Comment: @pepperjack ,if first string is empty as you said then am i getting right  output(by just keeping '=' sign in front of n), i understand its not a good way but then why am i getting right output.

Comment: @SrjSunny I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you are saying. Is the output wrong?

Comment: @pepperjack no the output is right ,just put an '=' mark in loop and see .

Comment: @pepperjack n=3, for(i=0;i<=n;i++), i'am able to enter three strings , though technically the loop is working 2 times only

Comment: @pepperjack #include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
int main()  
{   
int n; 
cin>>n; 
char str[n][100]; 
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++) 
{  
cin.clear(); 
char c;   
int j=0; 
while((c=getchar())!='\n') 
{  
str[i][j++] = c; 
}  
str[i][j] ='\0'; 
} 

for(int k=0;k<=n;k++)
{ int z=0; 
while(str[k][z]!='\0')
{ 
  
cout<<str[k][z]; 
z=z+2;  
}  
cout<<endl; 
}  
}

Comment: @pepperjack after using cin.ignore() its working as you said, it helped alot thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reading the `\n` return character (from when you filled `n`) and making the first string empty. Just do another `getchar()` before the first test for end of input to get rid of it.

For robustness, you could also try: `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);cin.clear();cin.sync();`.

Example (My compiler doesn't like part of your syntax so I had to redo it, focus on the new `getchar`:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char** str = new char*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str[i] = new char[100];

    getchar();

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        char c;
        int j = 0;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            str[i][j++] = c;
        }
        str[i][j] = '\0';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] str[i];
    delete[] str;
}
```

(Yes I know I'm 1 star away from http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer, just doing this to answer the question.)

Comment: but isn't that n declared outside the loop ang getchar is inside the loop and i'm reading c not n, will you please elaborate

Comment: That has nothing to do with it @SrjSunny. When you `cin>>n`, it leaves a `\n` left over in the cin buffer that is read by `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')` which makes `str[0]` empty.

Comment: now i get it , thank you very much but why did you use another getchar() isn't it better to just keep an '=' sign before n in the loop

Comment: @SrjSunny if that fixes it, hit the checkmark to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :). I used another `getchar` to get rid of the leftover `\n`, I also included a snippet of code you could use for robustness.